# Integrate all estimated states from a LQG controller?

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations, matlab, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I'm trying an expriment right now. I want to integrate all estimated states from a LQG controller. A LQG controller is a linear time domain controller which have proportional state feedback with filter for noise.

The LQG can estimate all the states from just one states. That's mean that I can know every velocity and deplacement in the system, just by looking at one velocity or one deplacement e.g a shaft position or a cylinders speed.

And of course! The LQG have a kalman filter. It's a optimal estimator which also reduce noise from measurement.

Here is a diagram of a LQG controller:

- A = System matrix.
- B = Signal matrix.
- C = Output matrix.
- K = Kalman gain matrix (The LQE controller)
- L = Control law matrix (The LQR controller)
- $\frac{1}{s}$ = Integrator
- $\dot{\hat{x}}$ = Estimated derivative state
- $\hat{x}$ = Estimated state
- $\dot{x}$ = Derivative state
- $x$ = State
- $ym$ = Measured output
- $ye$ = Estimated output
- $r$ = Reference signal
- $u$ = Signal

[image]

To do this. Just simulate this MATLAB / Octav code

```
dt = 1;
t = 0;
for i = 1:1000
  % State space model
  dx = A*x + B*u; % Compute the dx
  % Observer
  destx = A*estx + B*u + K*(C*x - C*estx); % Cx = ym, C*estx = ye
  % Compute the signal
  u = - L*estx + r;
  % Store the states in Y - Plot it later
  Y(i, :) = [t, x'];

  % Compute the next state by using integrator
  x = x + dx*dt;
  estx = estx + destx*dt;
  % Time
  t = t + dt;
endfor
```

But how would the code look like if the LQG looked like this:

- $N$ - Integrator gain matrix (The LQI controller)

Beacuse the LQG is just a simple "P-controller". And if the system have states with velocity (most of the time), the LQG controller is going a "PD-controller". Just because the $L$ matrix is just a matrix with real numbers.

So what do I need to add in the code to make the LQG have integral action?

[image]

**Edit:**
Can this be the right method?

```
dt = 1;
t = 0;
for i = 1:1000
  % State space model
  dx = A*x + B*u; % Compute the dx
  % Observer
  destx = A*estx + B*u + K*(C*x - C*estx); % Cx = ym, C*estx = ye
  % Compute the signal
  u = - L*estx + r - N*intestx; % <-- Added "N*intestx"
  % Store the states in Y - Plot it later
  Y(i, :) = [t, x'];

  % Compute the next state by using integrator
  x = x + dx*dt;
  estx = estx + destx*dt;
  intestx = intestx + estx*dt; % <-- intestx = integrate estimated x 
  % Time
  t = t + dt;
endfor
```

What do you think about integrating estimated states? Good or bad thing to do?

Here is an LQG example without integral action

[image]

Here is an LQG example with integral action

[image]

Comment: there is a [signal processing SE group](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).  you might wanna try that.

Comment: Thanks. But I think that I will stay here where everyone else staying.